# Xamarin Android Gridview with CustomAdapter Issue on ART

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i have problem with gridview and customadapter on android.
(Item Cell contains imageview, 3 textviews and 2 buttons)

2 physically devices (1 with android 4.3(dalvik), 1 with android 5.1.1 (art)).

On dalvik device the gridview is scrolling very smooth.
On ART device the gridview is scrolling very slow.

The images are loaded by asynctask called in getview.

Any suggestions?

Below is my code snippet for GetView:

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = _orderItemLoader.OrderItems[position];

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(_context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.OrderItemCell, parent, false);

        var tvDisplayName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvDisplayName);
        var tvDisplayAmount = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvDisplayAmount);
        var tvDisplayCount = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewQuantity);

        foreach (var _item in _orderItemLoader.OrderItems)
        {
            if (GetItemId(position) == _item.ItemId)
            {
                tvDisplayCount.Text = _item.Count.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        var btnPlus = itemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonPlus);
        btnPlus.Focusable = false;
        btnPlus.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
        btnPlus.Clickable = true;
        btnPlus.Tag = position;
        btnPlus.Click += (s, e) => 
        {
            int pos = (int)((Button)s).Tag;
            foreach (var itm in _orderItemLoader.OrderItems)
            {
                if (item.ItemId == GetItemId(position))
                {
                    item.Count += 1;

                    tvDisplayCount.Text = item.Count.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        var btnMinus = itemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonMinus);
        btnMinus.Focusable = false;
        btnMinus.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
        btnMinus.Clickable = true;
        btnMinus.Tag = position;
        btnMinus.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            int pos = (int)((Button)s).Tag;
            var tmpItem = GetItem(pos);
            if (tmpItem != null)
            {
                if (tmpItem.Count > 1)
                    tmpItem.Count -= 1;
                else
                    tmpItem.Count = 0;

                tvDisplayCount.Text = tmpItem.Count.ToString();
            }                
        };
        var imgThumbail = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgThumbnail);

        imgThumbail.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
        imgThumbail.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        tvDisplayName.Text = item.ItemName;
        tvDisplayName.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

        tvDisplayAmount.Text = ServiceManager.GetCurrency(item.Amount);
        tvDisplayAmount.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

        tvDisplayCount.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);

        new SetImageBitmapTask(item, imgThumbail, _activity).Execute("");

        return itemView;
    }
```

Comment: where is your asyn task code

Comment: look at picasso image loading libiary

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the performance of the lists using ViewHolder, I'll show you an example so that you can implement

ViewHolder:

```
public class StoreRecomendadaViewHolder : Object
    {
        public ImageView imgView { set; get; }
        public TextView txtView { set; get; }
    }
```

GetView:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        StoreRecomendadaViewHolder holder = null;
        var view = convertView;
        if (view != null)
            holder = view.Tag as StoreRecomendadaViewHolder;

        var item = items[position];

        if (holder == null)
        {
            holder = new StoreRecomendadaViewHolder();

            if (view == null)
            {
                Activity _activity = context;
                view = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ItemStoreRecomendada, null);
            }

            holder.imgView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgView);
            holder.txtView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtView);

            view.Tag = holder;
        }
        holder.txtView.SetText(item.NombreComercial, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        return view;
    }
```